# Drupal 7 : Add a more link in a block view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My view contains two blocks containing different content types.
I'd like to add a "Show more" button to each block. (More link)
(see link : [My view with two blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T6eT.png))

Currently I can display the button but it doesn't work. 
You can see the block view settings on this link : [my block view settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U6W3.png)
(This is my second block Content type B)

Why doesn't the button work?
Is it possible to add more than one button on a view?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: how url of more link looks like ?

Comment: the url redirects me to the current view. (<a href="/portfolio">
    Afficher la suite  </a>)

Comment: Do you want some kind of pager which show some more results when you click "More" button?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the 'more' link to work, you need to have a page display in that view with the appropriate path set. If you don't have a page display, the link won't show up. If you have see a link in the block, but it's pointing to the wrong place, the problem might be with your page display.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to pagers, check out the [Views Extra Pagers Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_extra_pagers).